# How can I record the internal audio of my musical app? (NOT from microphone!)

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I've published a MIDI-based app that generates sounds. I'd like to implement a REC button, to record and save/share the user's musical creations. I can't manage to find a solution to do that. I've found a lot of tutorials about how to record sounds from microphone or other external sources, but I care about the internal audio.

I'm using AVFoundation with an AVAudioEngine to which I've attached and connected a bunch of AVAudioUnitSampler with a DLS Soundbank loaded.

The app works great and it's already downloadable on the store, but recording is an important missing feature. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: “I'm just using AVFoundation.” Okay, but what parts of AVFoundation? Are you using an `AVAudioEngine`?

Comment: Thank you @robmayoff - I've edited the question: I'm using AVFoundation with an AVAudioEngine to which I've attached and connected a bunch of AVAudioUnitSampler with a DLS Soundbank loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have worked on an app that allow the user to export the sound and use it out of app. If the user can create sound freely, you should have an internal representation of that sound, that can be manipulated in memory. And the UI just presents that internal representation to the user.

It's the same case when you have an array of animals, for example, and present that array as a table view to the user.

There's another problem, if you record the sound, the sound must be played completely to be exported. Is it really necessary? Just rendering a 2 ~ 3 minutes sounds in 2 ~ 4 seconds sounds more reasonable.

So, you really must record the sound or it's just missing some in memory representation of it?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what Soundflower does. After installing it, in your app you set Soundflower(2) or Soundflower(64) as your output device (in the device list you'll also find Headphones and USB-out), then in your recording app you select Soundflower(2) or (64) as your input. I think my version of soundflower was installed by a Korg app. The (2) and (64) are the number of channels. (2) for stereo, and (64) for any number of channels out, up to 64 channels.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question? The question is about adding a record functionality in the app, not about how to record sound on your device.

Comment: The OP wants an Export function (to WAV or MIDI for example). Adding a Record button implies bringing sound INTO the app... which is not what the question was about. Soundflower allows audio to be captured as it is played out, even if the software doesn't allow for audio to be exported.